# Perfect numbers: why does the nested if isn't working?

Tags: c

I'm working on the next code to determine if a provided number is perfect or not:

```
int main(void)  {
long int n;
long int sum = 0;
int i;
scanf("%ld", &n);
int divisores[40];
for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    if(n % i == 0)  {
        divisores[i] = i;
        divisores[i+1] = n / divisores[i];
        if(divisores[i+1] != 1 && divisores[i] != 1 && divisores[i+1] != n && divisores[i] != n)    {
            sum = sum + divisores[i] + divisores[i+1];
        }
        printf("%d %d %ld\n", divisores[i], divisores[i+1], sum);
    }
}
return (0);
```

So far the code does find divisors. I put an if, so when the divisor is equal to 1 or provided number, it doesn't add it. It does work for when the divisor is 1, but not for the other case.

Can someone please point out where I'm wrong?

Thank you and regards.

Comment: Have you stepped through in a debugger to see what's going on?

Comment: You appear to be overwriting array entries already populated. Each `i` iteration populates `d[i]` and `d[i+1]`, the latter which is overwritten on the next iteration. I suspect the only thing saving you from the consequences is the fact you never again *use* the array. You could probably get away with just two variables rather than an array.

Comment: Isn't 6 a perfect number because 1+2+3 = 6? In other words, I think you always want to *include* 1. As for excluding `n`, just change `i <= n` to `i < n` in the `for` statement.

Comment: Yes, you're all right: the array entries were filled, so the values were being overwitten.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting previously computed array elements. But you don't need an array for this task; you just need to keep track of the sum of the divisors. So a simple implementation could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    unsigned long n, sum, i;

    while (scanf("%lu", &n) == 1) {
        sum = 1;
        for (i = 2; i < n / i; ++i)
            if (n % i == 0)
                sum += i + n / i;
        if (i * i == n)
            sum += i;
        printf("Sum: %lu\n", sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, M. Nejat Aydin,
yes, indeed, sadly I have to look for the answer because I wasn't  able to come up with a solution without arrays. Unwisely I only was patching up this code.
Thank you once again.